# Idiom: When something is not dealt with for a long time

Tags: idioms

What idiom could express when something is not dealt with for a very long time?
The reason would be that a certain issue or thing cannot be solved because you lack the necessary means/agreements to do it. So you finally have to give up and just wait. Perhaps 1 year, 10 years, 50 years, or even never. 
In Danish we say that "it ended up in the bag with the mothballs", or "it collects dust on the shelf".
What do you say in English?

Comment: [Mothballed](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mothball#mothball__14) and [shelved](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/shelve#shelve__9) are certainly used in English.

Comment: Ah, silly me! Don't know why I couldn't find it. Thank you :)

Comment: "It's being acted on by Congress" works in the US.

Comment: Hot Licks is joking. Please don't use that in any formal setting :)

Answer (score 2):

Although not for exactly the same reasons mentioned in your question, something that is (or can be) delayed is sometimes “[put/kept on the back burner.](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+the+back+burner)”  “Back-burner” delays are more temporary than those of the “mothballed” and “shelved” varieties and they generally result from a determination that “it CAN wait” (as opposed to “it MUST wait” as is implied in your question).

Such "back-burner" determinations, however, do involve the “[re-]allocation of resources,” which is similar to your mention of “lack[ing] the necessary means.”

Another expression, similar in nature to “on the shelf” involves putting/keeping something, usually of value, “[in the bottom drawer](https://books.google.com/books?id=_MscAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA123&lpg=PA123&dq=%22put%20it%20in%20the%20bottom%20drawer%22&source=bl&ots=DKDlSNlyZ9&sig=IMRRUj8VT6q2BIyoXXbmus4ySV4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=JtsuVePRIO6xsATxuIEI&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22put%20it%20in%20the%20bottom%20drawer%22&f=false),” either to be forgotten altogether (as with patents, mentioned below) or to be gotten to later at a more advantageous time (as with future brides mentioned [here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bottom-drawer?q=bottom%20drawer)).
Holders of patents have been known to keep their [patents “in the bottom drawer”](https://books.google.com/books?id=IhXP6Va3bvAC&pg=PA226&lpg=PA226&dq=%22put%20it%20in%20the%20bottom%20drawer%22%20patent&source=bl&ots=4l6moEO-Lz&sig=P2kCB00VDv4QMdckbJeYt5x72HQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=S9wuVdKWO4T7sASUp4H4Bw&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22put%20it%20in%20the%20bottom%20drawer%22%20patent&f=false) or just "[hidden in a drawer](https://books.google.com/books?id=7QfwAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA35&lpg=PA35&dq=%22hidden%20in%20a%20drawer%22%20patent&source=bl&ots=ErQO2FEqGl&sig=VGehLYwLMI81gEKlUoawe-RQxk4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=yesuVfCuI4v5yQT_4YGwCg&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22hidden%20in%20a%20drawer%22%20patent&f=false)" when the new invention would conflict with/cause harm to their current business.

Answer (score 0):

*To freeze* is used to refer to a temporaty stop in the development of something:

> - (tr) to stop (a process) at a particular stage of development. (TFD)

- The road project has been temporarily  frozen for lack of public fonds.

Answer (score 0):

When something is not dealt with for a long time, it is left to "**languish**" ([in obscurity](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-french/to%20languish%20in%20obscurity)).
(=**make no progress**)

- the economy will continue to *languish* until the public regains
  confidence

Answer (score 0):

If you have not used something for a long time, it is certainly idiomatic to say "it's collecting dust"<sup>1</sup> just as you would in Danish.

Example:

*I haven't used my iPod Touch in like 6 months. It's somewhere collecting dust.*

[Source (Wiktionary)<sup>1</sup>](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/collect_dust)

Answer (score 0):

**Delinquent**: Due to his delinquent attendance the farm was lost....

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/delinquent